# Task.WaitAll(...) blocks on MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, io, task-parallel-library, async-await

In a MVC 4 application I have a task that copies a file to a destination folder. Because I have multiple files, I create a task for every file, and I want to wait untill they all finish. The problem is my code blocks at `Task.WaitAll(copyingTasks.ToArray())` as if the tasks never end, so it never passes that line of code. Below you have the sample code:

```
    private void CopyFilesFromWorkingCopyForProject(string projectName)
    {
        var copyingTasks = new List<Task>
            {
                CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidConfigsPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
                CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidValuesPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
                CopyFileToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidManifestPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
                CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.IosConfigsPath(), FilesUtils.IosPathForProject(projectName))

            };
        Task.WaitAll(copyingTasks.ToArray());
    }

    private async Task CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(string sourceDirectory, string destinationDirectory)
    {
        foreach (string filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory))
        {
            await CopyFileToDirectory(filename, destinationDirectory);
        }
    }

    private async Task CopyFileToDirectory(string filename, string destinationDirectory)
    {
        using (FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(destinationDirectory + filename.Substring(filename.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

If I comment  `Task.WaitAll(copyingTasks.ToArray());` it doesn't block anymore, but I want to wait for all the files to be copied.

Comment: And is there any copying being done?  I'm not seeing where the Tasks are started.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Combining `await` and synchronous wait leads to deadlocks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), because `async` methods try to resume on the context that's currently blocked by your wait.

What you should do instead is to make `CopyFilesFromWorkingCopyForProject()` also `async` (and the method that calls that, and the method that calls that, …):

```
private async Task CopyFilesFromWorkingCopyForProject(string projectName)
{
    var copyingTasks = new List<Task>
        {
            CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidConfigsPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
            CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidValuesPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
            CopyFileToDirectory(FilesUtils.AndroidManifestPath(), FilesUtils.AndroidPathForProject(projectName)),
            CopyAllFromDirectoryToDirectory(FilesUtils.IosConfigsPath(), FilesUtils.IosPathForProject(projectName))

        };
    await Task.WhenAll(copyingTasks);
}
```

If you can't or don't want to do that, you need to make sure the `async` methods don't resume on the current context. To do that, you can use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for all your `await`s, or you can call the `async` methods on a background thread using `Task.Run()`.